Lando recipes are not available in Windows 11
I am using a Windows 11 machine with docker desktop and WSL.
I am trying to setup a new Drupal project (existing cloned one or recommended project clone using composer).
But whenever I am trying to initialize the project using lando init it gives me the following here.

What am I missed here?
I have php, composer, nodejs, npm installed in my system.
I am adding an update to Clives answer:
Its giving recipes options as none for new project also.


What is the lando version and what does lando version --component @lando/drupal return?

Trying from the project root returning the same, but from outside its undefined

It is "returning same" what? What is the same?

drupal10 is not a valid recipe error message

You seem not to be answering my questions, but someone else's.

Drupal Answers is not the right place for Lando or DDEV support questions. StackOverflow is a better place.

Please delete from here then i will ask in SO. dont downvote

I think deleting is something that you do. @KTM

Lando stopped bringing out new recipes for each Drupal update after v9.
The recipe you need is called drupal9, not drupal10.

Tried with drupal9 too. The thing is its not listing any recipes at all.

I updated Qn based on your answer
